# iOS: Run singleton instance always in the background (different thread)

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, singleton

I have a singleton class that manage the whole Core Data write&read methods and sometimes (due to JSON parsing and multiple objects savings) this singleton (that now runs in the main thread) blocks the UI.

I'm using the follow code to create the Singleton instance:

```
static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    });
});
return sharedInstance;
```

How do I create this instance in a different thread to have all the database tasks done in the background? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't create the instance in another thread (or at least you don't need to). It's more a question of which thread you run methods on when you edit content. So, it's more of a Core Data setup question.

i.e. If you create the instance in a background thread but call a method on it from the main thread then that method will still run on the main thread.

If you create a MOC for the singleton (so it isn't using the main queue MOC) and run any update on that MOC using `performBlock:` then it will run on the thread associated with the context instead of the main thread.

---

From your comment, you would need to verify the thread at the start of each method implementation and switch to a different thread if necessary (which could be done simply by recalling the same method after switching thread).

There is nothing automatic to do that, you need to code it yourself.

Be aware that your MOC should only be used on 1 thread so you need to be careful about how you access it and using `performBlock:` is highly recommended...

Comment: Hi @Wain, this is the thing. I could run each call for this class in a different thread but it will give me more work. I would like to run any method in this class in a different thread, doesn't matter if the one that calls was a main thread or not. Plus I don't want to perform any UI update in this class (it's a model class). You're saying that it's not possible or you don't recommend it?

Comment: Remember that a Managed Object Context (MOC) can only work in _one_ thread and all the objects that it manages must only be used in that one thread. It doesn't care at all what you want or not want; use it in a different thread and it crashes.

Comment: Thanks @Wain. I will go with other approach. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Which 'other' approach? If neither of the answers are acceptable to you then please add your own answer so you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Grand Central Dispatch to run the contents of the methods of the singleton on whatever thread you prefer. Look into dispatch_async as an example.

Comment: Hi @nsdebug, this is one option, of course, but I'm trying to avoid this because I would need to take care of each method (I have many). That's why I would like to create an instance that runs every method in a different thread already.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it - you can easily put a dispatch block inside each method and that will handle the thread switching automatically for you. You can always make a macro and wrap your methods with calls to the macro. Another option is funky method swizzling but then you are just making things more complex IMO.

Comment: Thanks @nsdebug. I will go with other approach. Thank you very much for your time.